# socket programming with python on linux - s.connect() time-out

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I'm using a TCP socket to connect to a certain web page, as it will be running in a loop trying to create socket, connect, send data, and receive then close the socket. the problem is s.connect() times out at random iterations and specific web site. i read about TCP time_wait so

```
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

was added with no luck. then one second of sleep after each iteration, but still no luck.
i should note that it works fine in another slower network, but not in the fast one i'm trying to run the code.
i think following pseudo code can clarify it more:

```
while(1)
{time.sleep(1)
s = socket.socket() #TCP socket creation
s.settimeout(2) # 2 seconds for time-out which is more than needed
s.connect()
s.send(message) #which is a HTTP get request
s.recv() # which is a HTTP response
s.close()}
```

my code routine follows these steps, each of socket methods are implemented correctly, but i get time-outs on connect. i am sure about server functioning correctly. i suspected it might have something to do with TCP time_wait , but  comments don't seem to agree

Answer (score 1):

A connect times out if the TCP handshake with the server is not finished within a specific time, usually because the server does not respond in time. There might be various reasons for is, like the server being down, getting the wrong IP address for the server during DNS lookup, server being overloaded etc.

> s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

Adding this on the client side on the connection has no use.

Adding this on the server side will help if the problem was caused by a crashed server since it will allow the server to bind to the listener address again without waiting and thus the server is faster available again. But, I have no idea if this is really the problem you are facing.

Comment: thanks for the clarification on REUSEADDR . the problem is none of the ones you mentioned though, as it occurs when i try to connect in a loop as i mentioned before, output is like : time-out , success with RTT = 8 ms, success with RTT=7ms, time-out

Comment: @HamedTemsah did you set any explicit connect timeout? Are you closing the connections cleanly between re-connects?

Comment: @HamedTemsah: how do you know that this is none of server being down and server being overloaded? Do you have control of the server? And, do you maybe set a very short connection timeout?

Comment: tnx smassey and steffen , i edited the Q, maybe it makes it more clear.

Comment: @HamedTemsah: I see you have a timeout of 2 only. In this case I assume that the server is simply busy and will not react that fast. This can also happen if other things run on the same machine and eat resources like CPU time or memory. Of course there might also a rate limiting be installed at the server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks for your help, but i think that is not the case, as when i change my connection to another ISP i have, with slower network, it works fine, RTT for the first network is somewhere around 10ms but the second network that works fine reports 100ms RTT.

Comment: @HamedTemsah: if you have a faster network to the same server then you can "hammer" the server faster which means that the server gets more load from your client than on the slower network. Thus, the chance of overloading or of activated rate limiting is higher.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich , i don't use both networks simultaneously , i have tried them both at separate time, one never time outs and the other is successful on connect less than half the times

Comment: @HamedTemsah: have you also compared how many connections per second you get on average for each network?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich no, how can i get that info?

Comment: @HamedTemsah: count the total connects and divide by the total time?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich , thanks for your tips . as they both make certain number of connections, the connect trials are the same, but faster network will get more connection per second as it consumes less time (remember the less RTT therefore less total running time)

Comment: @HamedTemsah: that's exactly what I expected - it will get more connections per second on the faster connection. This means it will put more load on the server on the faster connection and will thus be more likely to cause overloading and/or triggering some rate limit. If you reduce how fast you connect (i.e. how many connect attempts per time) the problem might vanish.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich doesn't my time.sleep(1) do that? i try every one second, which changes the connection per second to a very low speed, much lower than the slow network

Comment: @HamedTemsah: sorry, but I actually did not notice all the time that you have this 1 second sleep. In this case there is probably neither overloading nor rate limiting the issue.